# iterate through a Twitter stream using tweepy

Tags: python, tweepy

I have this code to create a Stream within tweepy (my goal is to get a stream of all mentions of a person):

```
class StreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):
    def on_status(self, status):
        print(status.text)
    def on_error(self, status_code):
        if status_code == 420:
        #returning False in on_data disconnects the stream
        return False

l = StreamListener()
stream = tweepy.Stream(auth = api.auth, listener=l)
```

I was wondering how I could use each mention with a `tweepy.Stream` object?
I have tried something like:

```
for mention in tweepy.Cursor(stream.filter(track=['@twitter'])).items():
    *code*
```

But that just creates a stream that I cannot manipulate or use. I am interested in a way that I can use any mention of that person?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that just converting the data gotten from the stream to json lets me use the data!

```
class StreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):
    def on_data(self, data):
        data = json.loads(data)
        print(data.text)
    def on_error(self, status_code):
        if status_code == 420:
        #returning False in on_data disconnects the stream
        return False
```